# The attribute [] is not present in the managed type

Tags: jpa

I'm doing an application that has this relation ship: A personal contact has an Email.

So i'm trying to find the Emails from the personal contact and I'm doing this query using Criteria but always return `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
@Override
public Email findByEmail(PersonalContact personalContact) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Email> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Email.class);
    Root<Email> email = criteriaQuery.from(Email.class);

    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(
            email.get("personalContact"), criteriaBuilder.parameter(PersonalContact.class, "personalContact")));

    TypedQuery<Email> typedQuery = entityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    typedQuery.setParameter("personalContact", personalContact);

    return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

Personal contact is like a foreign key.

And here is my Email class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Email")
public class Email implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String mainEmail;
    private List<String> secondaryMail;

    @JoinColumn(name = "personal")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PersonalContact pContact;
```

and here is my Personal Contact class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONALCONTACT")
public class PersonalContact extends Contact implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PERSONAL_ID")
    private Long id;

    //Other variables

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="personal")
    private Email email;
```

And every time I execute the query this is the return:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [personalContact] is
>   not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@1230307250:Email [
>   javaType: class csheets.ext.crm.contact.Email descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(csheets.ext.crm.contact.Email -->
>   [DatabaseTable(Email)]), mappings: 5]].

I did some search and the others programmers said the problem was on the name of the variables... but i guess the names of the variables are correct.

So what I'm doing wrong? perhaps the relationship between that two classes?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you persisting `private List<String> secondaryMail;`? You can't store a list in a single row. Are you missing another table?

Answer (score 7):

If you read the exception message carefully, you'll find that it is complaining that class `Email` does not have a property (attribute) called `personalContact`, and indeed, there is no such property. Presumably you meant the `pContact` property?

(Mistakes such as this are why I recommend querying JPA via [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/): code completion would likely have prevented this mistake, and even if not, you would have gotten a clear compiler message when trying to use a non-existing property)

Comment: That was my mistake, thank you .. i thought i had everything correctly ... Sorry for that silly question! And once again thank you for your answer!